# antecedent of relative pronoun 'which'

Tags: relative-pronouns

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> The irony is that despite all of Buterin’s cachet, he may not have the
> ability to prevent Ethereum from veering off course. That’s because he
> designed it as a decentralized platform, responsive not only to his
> own vision but also to the will of its builders, investors, and ever
> sprawling community. Buterin is not the formal leader of Ethereum. And
> he fundamentally rejects the idea that anyone should hold unilateral
> power over its future.
>
> **Which** has left Buterin reliant on the limited tools of soft power: writing blog posts, giving interviews, conducting research, speaking
> at conferences where many attendees just want to bask in the glow of
> their newfound riches. “I’ve been yelling a lot, and sometimes that
> yelling does feel like howling into the wind,” he says, his eyes
> darting across the room. Whether or not his approach works (and how
> much sway Buterin has over his own brainchild) may be the difference
> between a future in which Ethereum becomes the basis of a new era of
> digital life, and one in which it’s just another instrument of
> financial speculation—credit-default swaps with a utopian patina.

Is the antecedent of 'Which' in bold the sentence '*And he fundamentally rejects the idea that anyone should hold unilateral power over its future*.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a kind of stylistic thing. It is essentially identical in meaning to as if they had written:

> **This** has left...

There isn't necessarily a very clear grammatical antecedent, just a general idea that this next paragraph builds on.

Comment: Thank you very much.